# How can I filter questions with ZERO answers for a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions, sorting

I tried to answer SEO-related questions which are not having even a single answer in Pro Webmasters. But I was not able to filter a single question with no answer in the SEO tag. Why does it show questions with answers even if I filter “unanswered” in the SEO tag? If no question is available in this case, it should say ”No question is available for this filter criteria”.

I’m sure that there are lot of unanswered questions in SEO tag. How can I filter those questions?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, *unanswered*  means that the questions have no answers that are either upvoted or accepted.

If “unanswered” questions have answers, none of the answers have been accepted or upvoted – meaning that no one in the community thought they were good answers. We kinda take that to mean that the OP didn’t in fact get a satisfactory answer, hence unanswered.

To get only questions with no answers at all, you can add a filter for zero answers: `answers:0`
Like [this](http://www.webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bseo%5D+answers%3A0).

Comment: But my opinion is we can have a separate option like **unresolved questions** for all the questions which are not having accepted answers. New users won't think like filtering questions with 0 answers by using `answers:0` in search box.

Comment: I agree that the naming is not obvious. Naming is hard...